# How mix rows around in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that contains many binary columns. In the first half, each row has at least a 1; on the second half, each row has all zeros across all columns.

Is there a function to randomize rows so that they are not grouped by rows that have at least one 1 and rows that have all zeros?

Thank you!

Comment: well if you just want to see data you can do `df.sample(n=50)` it will, show you 50 rows in randomized order

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's good to know; however, this time  I want to mix around the rows in the entire df.

Comment: you can use `df = df.sample(frac=1)`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use .sample(n) on your pandas dataframe to view a random sample of n items if that is all you need...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's good to know; however, this time I want to mix around the rows in the entire df.

Comment: You could try: df_random = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True).

Comment: Thank you for your help!